# PHP MySQL Task API, Prevent Duplicate Records

Tags: php, mysql, concurrency, task

I am building a PHP RESTful-API for remote "worker" machines to self-assign tasks. The MySQL InnoDB table on the API host holds pending records that the workers can pick up from the API whenever they are ready to work on a record.  How do I prevent concurrently requesting worker system from ever getting the same record?

My initial plan to prevent this is to UPDATE a single record with a uniquely generated ID in a default NULL field, and then poll for the details of the record where the unique ID field matches.

For example:

```
UPDATE mytable SET status = 'Assigned', uniqueidfield = '3kj29slsad' 
WHERE uniqueidfield IS NULL LIMIT 1
```

And in the same PHP instance, the next query:

```
SELECT id, status, etc FROM mytable WHERE uniqueidfield = '3kj29slsad'
```

The resulting record from the SELECT statement above is then given to the worker.  Would this prevent simultaneously requesting workers from getting the same records shown to them?  I am not exactly sure on how MySQL handles the lookups within an UPDATE query, and if two UPDATES could "find" the same record, and then update it sequentially.  If this works, is there a more elegant or standardized way of doing this (not sure if FOR UPDATE would need to be applied to this)?  Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nevermind my previous answer.  I believe I understand what you are asking.  I'll reword it so maybe it is clearer to others.

"If I issue two of the above update statements at the same time, what would happen?"

According to http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/lock-tables-restrictions.html, the second statement would not interfere with the first one.

> Normally, you do not need to lock tables, because all single UPDATE
>   statements are atomic; no other session can interfere with any other
>   currently executing SQL statement.

A more elegant way is probably opinion based, but I don't see anything wrong with what you're doing.